# How to pass VideoElement currentTime into a controller of Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a VideoElement with id="videoElement" where

```
$('#videoElement')[0].currentTime;
```

gives me time which a video is playing at.

On my controller I have a method

```
setTime(time)
```

where time is the value of the video elements currentTime value.

How can I pass this value to it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this (after Mathew's comment below as my solution initially was tying the controller to the view):

```
app.directive('currentVideoPlayTime', function () {
var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('timeupdate', function () {
        scope.currentPlayTime = element[0].currentTime;
    });
};

return {
    restrict:'A',
    link:linker
}
```

});

Comment: You can accomplish the click event and stay within angular like this `element.bind('click', function(){ ... });`, no need to branch out to jquery. Also, I would create a directive that would wire up to your videoControl id element and then adjust the time through that. If you could provide a jsfiddle I can help you along.

Comment: Thank you Mathew, I'll take up your jsFiddle offer some other time. I think I have got it working with your suggestion.